# Kaleidoscope Effect in Android

Tags: java, android, matrix

I'm trying to create a Kaleidoscope with an ImageView in Android. I'm struggling to get the rotation and mirroring for each 'segment' correct. I'm new to image manipulation and I'm trying to adapt the code example from [here](https://github.com/dbu/kaleidoscope/blob/master/kaleidoscope_image/Kaleidoscope.pde) for android.

I have the following code:

```
private void drawKaleidoscope() {

    Bitmap bm               = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cropped_landscape);
    Bitmap imageview_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
    Bitmap matrix_bitmap;
    BitmapShader fillShader;

    Path triangle_mask    = new Path();
    RectF r               = new RectF(0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight()); // create new rectangle to match the dimensions of our image
    this.radius           = (int)r.height() / 2;

    Canvas c = new Canvas(imageview_bitmap);
    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);


    float start_angle = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < this.segments; i++) {

        // Create pie-slice shape mask
        triangle_mask.reset();
        triangle_mask.moveTo(r.centerX(), r.centerY());
        triangle_mask.arcTo(r, start_angle, angle);
        triangle_mask.close();


        // Use odd even check to decide when to mirror the image or not
        if (i % 2 == 0) {

            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            mat.preTranslate(-radius, -radius);
            mat.postRotate(i * angle);
            mat.postTranslate(radius, radius);

            matrix_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, (int)r.width(), (int)r.height(), mat, true);
        }
        else {

            Matrix mat = new Matrix();

            // mirror on x axis
            mat.postScale(-1, 1);

            mat.postTranslate(-radius, radius);
            mat.postRotate((float)-Math.PI);
            mat.postRotate(i * angle);
            mat.postTranslate(radius, -radius);


            matrix_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, (int)r.width(), (int)r.height(), mat, true);
        }

        fillShader = new BitmapShader(matrix_bitmap, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);


        // Fill the triangle masked area with our image now
        Paint fill = new Paint();
        fill.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        fill.setShader(fillShader);

        c.drawPath(triangle_mask, fill);
        start_angle += angle;
    }


    kal.setImageBitmap(imageview_bitmap);
}
```

The output of the above function looks like so:

[image]

If anyone could provide some insight on how to properly do the image rotations/mirroring that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I ended up going about this a different way. Instead of rotating the source image I simply draw the image mask to the same spot on the canvas, and then rotate the canvas itself. Let's say I have 12 image 'slices'. I draw 6 alternating segments, flip the canvas via canvas.scale(-1, 1) and then draw another 6 segments in where the blank spaces are. Here's the code I ended up with:

```
private Bitmap generateKaleidoscopeBitmap(float start_angle) {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageview_bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    BitmapShader fillShader;

    Path triangle_mask    = new Path();
    RectF r               = new RectF(0, 0, imageview_bitmap.getWidth(), imageview_bitmap.getHeight()); // create new rectangle to match the dimensions of our image

    int centerX = imageview_bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = imageview_bitmap.getHeight() / 2;

    // how much to rotate the canvas by after the image is flipped
    float offset = calculateCanvasSymmetryOffset(start_angle);


    // Create a pie-slice shaped clipping mask
    triangle_mask.moveTo(r.centerX(), r.centerY());
    triangle_mask.arcTo(r, start_angle, angle);
    triangle_mask.close();


    // Fill the triangle masked area with our shader now
    Paint fill = new Paint();
    fill.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    fillShader = new BitmapShader(source_image, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
    fill.setShader(fillShader);


    // Rotate the canvas and draw the clipping mask to the canvas
    for (int i = 0; i < this.segments / 2; i++) {

        canvas.drawPath(triangle_mask, fill);
        canvas.rotate(angle * 2, centerX, centerY);
    }


    // mirror the canvas and rotate it once to counter the symmetrical offset
    canvas.scale(-1, 1, centerX, centerY);
    canvas.rotate(offset, centerX, centerY);


    // Rotate the now mirrored canvas and draw the clipping mask to it
    // This is a cheap and easy way of creating mirrored segments
    for (int i = 0; i < this.segments / 2; i++) {

        canvas.drawPath(triangle_mask, fill);
        canvas.rotate(angle * 2, centerX, centerY);
    }

    return imageview_bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you share calculateCanvasSymmetryOffset() function?